# Magento2 : Undefined Index amount in Order/Totals/Tax.phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I installed one GST module on my local instance. after installing that module i am unable to create invoice for sales order. Getting the attached error message.I disabled all my third party extensions including GST extension as well. Still i am getting issue. [image]

Comment: I found the issue , I changed settings from Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings -> Show Full Summary to -> No. Then everything works.